# Force Scrapy Scheduler to Execute a Request

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy, python-requests

In my spider, I am returned 500 JSON objects. For each object, I then have to make a request to the webpage of that object, and scrape the data from that webpage.

Before the item goes through the pipeline, I have to have the data already scraped from the corresponding webpage.

I think my problem occurs when I create a new scrapy `Request`. Even if the `priority` of that request is absurdly high, it still hasn't parsed the previous `start_urls` it made requests for, so the new request simply sits in the queue until there is an open spot for concurrent requests.

Is there any way to force scrapy to execute the new request, block on that item until the request is done and page scraped, or should I go against the core of the `scheduler` and just use the `requests` module?

Comment: Could you make it a bit more specific and clear by providing a code (or the relevant part of it) you have so far? Thanks.